# Can someone please explain the greediness in this regex

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have some text where each line of text has some good words and some bad(unwanted) words. So the pattern might look like this

```
good1-good2 good3 bad1-good4-bad2 some more good words
good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 
good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 bad3
```

Now i need to reject everything in a line following and including the first bad word
So

`good1-good2 good3 bad1-good4-bad2 some more good words` should become `good1-good2 good3`

`good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2` should become `good1-good2 good3`

`good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 bad3` should become `good1-good2 good3`

I am using python so this was what i did

```
p=re.compile('([\w \d-]+) (bad1|bad2|bad3).+',re.I)
m=p.search('good1-good2 good3 bad1-good4-bad2 ')
m.group(1)
```

and this gives `good1-good2 good3` 
which is what i want but

```
m=p.search('good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 ')
m.group(1)
```

returns `good1-good2 good3 bad1`
I thought that because the `+` is greedy so the `+` in `([\w \d-]+)` goes on matching characters till the end of the line and then it backtracks to find the last bad word which in this case is `bad2` but when i do this

```
p=re.compile('([\w \d-]+) (bad1|bad2|bad3).+',re.I)
m=p.search('good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 bad3')
m.group(1)
```

it again returns `good1-good2 good3 bad1`.
Can you please explain that? Because there might be a problem with my understanding of `greediness` in regex? Although i have figured out to solve this problem 
by using a regex like this `([\w \d-]+?) (bad1|bad2|bad3).+` but still i do not understand why using `([\w \d-]+) (bad1|bad2|bad3).+` always returns the first bad word(bad1 in this case)?

Thanks for the time.

**Edit:** 
But suppose i have a pattern with only good words and no bad words like
`good1-good2 good3--only good words` then what should be the regex?
i tried this regex `([\w \d-]+?) ?(bad1|bad2|bad3)?.*` but this returns the first letter of the pattern.

Comment: The first sub-pattern is also greedy, so it gets the most it can match, then the second one, etc...

Comment: @poncha my problem is the third case. why does it return `good1-good2 good3 bad1` when i am looking in `good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 bad3`? It should have returned `good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2` according to my understanding of greedy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding this case:

```
m=p.search('good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 ')
```

You are correct.  `([\w \d-]+)` is greedy so it "eats" as much as possible and backtracks.

Regarding this case however:

```
m=p.search('good1-good2 good3 bad1 bad2 bad3')
```

What you're probably not seeing is that your `.+` has to match *at least one character after the bad word*.  That's why the regex can't match `bad3` as the bad word: if it did, it'd run out of characters for the `.+` to match anything.  Thus, it backtracks to `bad2` once again.  Change your `.+` to `.*` to see the difference.  It's only because you happened to have an extra space in the first case, *i.e.* `bad2` , that things "worked out as expected" there.

In other words, some unfortunate coincidences left you confused; but your understanding of greediness is sound.

**EDIT**

For the edited part of the question, as written by @lovesh from the comments below:

```
([\w \d-]+?) ?(bad1|bad2|bad3|$)
```

Comment: i know i have accepted your answer but i just realized i had missed something. I have edited my question. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: In your edit, it's only returning the first letter because you made the first part non-greedy, i.e. ``([\w \d-]+?)``, so it would only need to match one letter while the ``.*`` takes the rest.  I've been thinking about a solution, but it's actually a tricky problem...  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have to ask, is it absolutely necessary that you do things this way?  For example, couldn't you just match ``bad1|bad2|bad3|...`` and then use ``m.start()`` to get the index of the first bad word, and then cut the original string from that index?

Comment: well i can do it this way. But i was looking for a way to do it "elegantly". I tried but couldnt think of how to it

Comment: I think I got it. ``^(.*?)(?=bad1|bad2|bad3|$)``. You can see it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/Ai1a96xPks. It basically says, "The shortest string followed by a bad word or the end-of-line." The ``$`` has to be the last in the alternation list for this to work.

Comment: By the way, the ``(?=...)`` is known as a "lookahead" if you don't already know and want to learn more about it.

Comment: Thanks. Thats smart. But i dont think you need the lookahead. I tried this `([\w \d-]+?)(bad1|bad2|bad3|$)` and `group(1)` works

Comment: You're right; not sure why I went with a lookahead.  I think I tried to solve the problem "from scratch" without looking at what you did, and I have a habit of preferring lookaheads.